# Making a Server Request Every Time an Ember Route is entered

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When an ember route is entered with a dynamic path, ember data will load the object preloaded in the store if it exists and not make a server request.  For example:

```
App.SomethingRoute=Ember.route.extend({
  model:function(params){
    this.store.find("something",params.something_id)
  }
})
```

My app is such that I don't want to perform updating of depend models server side(I will for simple relationships but there are other I want to just pull updated records from the server).  So I have been able to solve the problem by incorporating a server request in the afterModel hook:

```
App.SomethingRoute=Ember.route.extend({
  model:function(params){
    this.store.find("something",params.something_id)
  },
  afterModel:function(model){
    $.getJSON("/somethings/"+model.id).then(function(data){
        var serialized_something=route.store.serializerFor("something").normalize(TaxProgram.Something,data.something)
        route.store.update("something",serialized_something)
    })
})
```

What I can't figure out is how to check to see if the model hook is actually called, and in that case not make an additional wasteful afterModel call.  I could set a  property on the route that contains this information but I was hoping that Ember had a method to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no specific provision in Ember to handle the situation you describe.

In a similar situation I did exactly what you said you want to avoid, which is to set a property to remember if the `model` hook had been called. `beforeModel` is a useful place to initialize that property.

However, your implementation of this notion is flawed, and you're replicating too much Ember Data logic in your `afterModel` hook. Instead, you should simply consider using `unload` to remove the model instance from the local store when unnecessary and force a refresh next time you do a `find` on it, or do a `reload` at the appropriate point to force the reload.

Comment: I was unaware of the unload method.  My plan is to initialize the property as discussed in beforeModel and the replace the $.getJSON call with a simple model.reload().  In initial testing it seems to work perfectly.  Does that seem right?